# What is missing converting session tokens in python to swift?

Tags: swift

This is how I access http request with a token in python, which works without problems.

```
    import requests
    import ast
    session = requests.Session()
    session.cookies.set('auth_token', args.token)
    if not session.put("https://SomeWebAddress/audio/devices/1/volume", data=str(volume)).status_code == 200
          print("Error during sending the command")
```

In Swift 4.2, iOS 13.0, I'm trying

```
let url:URL = URL(string: "https://SomeWebAddress/audio/devices/1/volume")!
let session:URLSession = URLSession.shared
session.configuration.httpShouldSetCookies = true
var request:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpShouldHandleCookies = true
request.setValue(TOKEN, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
request.httpMethod = "POST"

request.httpBody = String(volume).data
```

as well as

```
 request.httpBody = String(volume) as Data
```

but end up with errors like

> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to type 'Data' in coercion

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what type of variable `volume`? I'd recommend using such a solution `request.httpBody = volume.data(using: .utf8)` if `volume` type can be converted to `Data`

Comment: @ Vadim Nikolaev  Thanks for the help. 'volume' is a double.  This seemed to work  'request.httpBody = String(volume).data(using: .utf8)'  if you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I've added as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using such a solution for `Double`

```
request.httpBody = String(volume).data(using: .utf8)
```

volume converts to `Data` and that's it